# In perl, how can I pattern match a string to see if a carriage return exists in a line

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I'm using this simple code to read a file and put in all values in an array.

```
open (TEXT_FILE, "$file_name") || die "can't open $_";
@file_data=<TEXT_FILE>;
close TEXT_FILE;
```

The file I'm reading is a text file and was edited using unix or windows either. So at the end of each line it might contain carriage return and line feed(in case of windows) and might contain a line feed only(in case of unix). I want to remove carriage return if exists.
I'm thinking something like this

```
foreach(@file_data)
{
 if($_ =~ /something to match a carriage return at the end of line/)
 {
   chop $_;
 }
 else{ #do nothing
 }
}
```

If I'm doing right then please suggest me some pattern else suggest some other options also.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in a quick fix, you might look into the `dos2unix` utility. In Perl, you could do

```
perl -pi -le 's/[\r\n]+\z//' yourfile.txt
```

The `-pi` performs in-place edit (no backup, unless you add an extension to `-i`), and the `-l` switch handles newlines for you (removing and putting back when printing).

If you want to use your own code, just apply the same regex within your loop.

Comment: foreach(@file_data) { if($_ =~ /\r/) { print "exists"; } else { print "does not exist"; } # I m using this but results are not ok !!

Comment: What did you hope to accomplish by copy/pasting the same comment on all our answers? None of us gave you that code, and none of us knows what you mean by "not ok".

Comment: I mean i m not able to match \r with this code. I don't know much perl so just pasted what I m doing actually.

Comment: hey thanks !! It worked, actually i was trying that code on windows but my requirement was on unix, I tried on unix and it worked fine.

Comment: You're welcome. If using my code in windows, you need to replace `'` with `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Carriage return is `\r`, so just do:

```
s/\r$//;
```

Comment: foreach(@file_data) { if($_ =~ /\r/) { print "exists"; } else { print "does not exist"; } # I m using this but results are not ok !!

Comment: @Mak_Thareja: In which way results aren't OK?

Comment: I mean when I tried this pattern match, I always got does not exist. It never went in IF condition. And \r exists in my file I can see that with notepad++.

Comment: thank u so much for your support. now I can detect \r. Actually I was trying on windows earlier, but I should have tried on unix, it is working fine. Thanks !! :)))

Comment: The script `perl -p -e 's/\r$//'` works correctly on Unix.  On Windows, you have different quoting conventions in the command language, and you'd have to use double quotes instead of single quotes and probably add an extra backslash before the backslash, etc.

Comment: @jonathan: Don't know, actually I was trying only the regex, but as windows can handle \r, so may be perl was not detecting \r but in unix \r creates problems and perl is able to detect it and now I can remove it.

Comment: Actually, that could well be a major part of the issue...on Windows, you'd have to open the file as a binary file to be able to remove the CR form the line endings. For a text file, the I/O system would automatically convert CRLF to NL as it is read, and translate back again as it is written.  So the internal code would not see the CR (and couldn't remove what isn't there), and the output would contain the CR again.  And that's all done at the C standard I/O levels or below.